# Controlling the brightness of multiple LEDs at once

Tags: arduino, pwm

I'm building a device for DJ-ing. When practicing at home I prefer the LEDs on the device to be quite bright, but when I'm in a club setting I'd like to dim them to my liking so that I'm not blinded by them. The brightness should be controlled via a potentiometer connected to an analogue input on my Arduino but I'm intending to switch the LEDs individually (no mutliplexing) with digital outputs.

I have a bunch of 2N3904 transistors so I thought maybe I could use them in some configuration, but I'm having a hard time finding a simple way to do this.

EDIT:
I'm happy to provide any additional information.

Regarding the LED's: I'm using 15 regular 5mm LED's.

Controller: [Meduino Mega2560 R3 Pro Mini](http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-Small-Meduino-Mega2560-R3-Pro-Mini-ATMEGA16U2-Arduino-Mega2560-Compatible-/161757302117).

Power: The device will be powered by a 9V wallwart but I'm not too sure if it's OK to use the 5v regulator output on the MCU-board.

Comment: Useful search term : "current mirror". LED brightness is controlled by current. You should find a "current mirror" circuit that lets you control any number of current sources by setting one current. 2N3904s will work nicely for thes.

Comment: "The LEDs". Which LEDs? What LEDs? We cannot, as a general rule, read minds. How many? What are you using for power to the LEDs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done this as an overall dimmer for panel lights:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFX8BO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a relaxation oscillator (the bottom part) compared to an adjustable reference (the top part).  The reference is a front-panel potentiometer that is padded with fixed resistors to match the voltage range of the oscillator.  I would recommend 10k resistors all around because they're easy to get, as well as the pot.  Choose the capacitor for a low-ish frequency that is still higher than you can see, like maybe 30Hz or above.  A 555 calculator may be useful because the voltage range is similar.

The PWM output then feeds one of these, depending on which is easier for you:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzGO3g.png)</sup>

As you can see, each LED is individually controlled from a digital output, and the common rail is controlled by the PWM'ed transistor.  Thus, OFF is still off, and ON is whatever brightness you set with the PWM generator.

Just make sure that your LED's can withstand the full supply worth of reverse voltage because they'll get that when the PWM is off and you're driving some LED's on and others off.  Or to avoid that problem, you could use the opposite type of transistor to control each LED, but I've never needed to.

This has the advantage (for me at least) of the processor not needing to care about the overall brightness.  For panel indicators, all the software needs to know is ON/OFF, and this analog circuit defines how bright ON actually is.

Comment: If I understand this correctly the problem with this circuit is that I'm trying to use a single pot for multiple tasks (controlling a parameter in "performance mode" and adjusting the brightness of the LED's in "setup mode" which will be managed by code). 

Also I don't want to add another pot to my casing for this single purpose as I have a layout that I'm already satisfied with and I don't see a fitting place for an additional pot.

Comment: Hmm.  So you want to re-use an existing pot that is already read by software to set a fixed value that will be used forevermore?  (or until the code restarts)  In that case, you might use a spare PWM output in place of my oscillator circuit.  The common-rail transistor would remain the same.  After reading the pot, do some math to figure out the appropriate PWM value, then forget you ever did anything while the on-chip hardware does its thing.

Comment: Or do you actually want a zero-hardware-change solution?  That would probably change the software *a lot* unless you designed it *very* well to start with.  As in "complete rewrite" kind of a lot.  But at least you know what you're doing now.  Guess how I know...

Comment: If you prefer a purely software solution, then you might have a look at this: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/148084/53375 It relies on an external zero-crossing detector to synchronize with the AC mains, but you can easily replace that part with a free-running counter in software.  With this solution, you no longer have ON/OFF, but a dedicated global variable for each channel.  The value of that variable determines individual brightness, which you'll now have to manage.  A master level is also possible, but again, you'll have to manage that...

Comment: ...This is in addition to spending *much* more CPU time driving the LED's than you are now.

Comment: The code part will be easy. I've written the code with two modes in mind from the beginning. I did hit the wall when I was trying to figure out the electronics part as this is not the strongest part of my skill set. I'm still designing the board so your solution seems simple enough for me to squeeze it on the board. But one last question before I go on to source some suitable transistors - will the overall brightness be affected by the number of LED's turned on?

Comment: Only if the supply droops or if the common-rail transistor is too high-impedance.  Look for low Rds_on and short switching times.  Insufficient CPU time for bit-banged PWM will show itself differently.

Comment: Yes. I understand that a pure software solution will be a waste of processing power. Using a singe PWM output will also save me from writing too much additional code and I also need the controls to feel responsive while I'm performing.